# How to add Java annotation over methods during runtime

Tags: java, annotations

I am using a **3rd party** library which has annotation named `@Video`. This annotation needs to be added on all the methods. There are more than 200 methods. Is there any way to add this annotation at **runtime** during execution ?

Comment: There's no way to add annotations at runtime. (You could possibly use some sort of tool to edit or generate class files, as the duplicate is suggesting, I guess, but the basic answer is "no".)

Comment: @Radiodef thank you for your help.